# a simple question about polynomials over z and $ {\overline z } $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let p be a complex valued polynomial of two ral variables:
$$
\sum {a_{ij} x^i y^j } 
$$
write:
$$p(z)=
\sum {P_j \overline z } ^j 
$$
where each $P_j$ is of the form $
P_j  = \sum {b_{ij} z^i } 
$
Prove that p is an entire function if and only iff $
P_j  \equiv 0
$

Clearly I have to consider the "derivate" $
P_{\overline z }  = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {P_x  + iP_y } \right)
$ , since the real and imaginary part are $C^1$ functions, being holomorphic it's equivalent of satisfy C.R , or equivalently $
P_{\overline z }  = 0
$ in this case
$$
P_{\overline z }  = \sum {jP_j \overline z ^{j - 1} }  = 0
$$
and now what can I do?

Comment: Suppose some $P_j$ weren't 0 everywhere; how could you still get your last line?

Comment: intuitively I think that it's imposible to have that equality for all the "z" except in the case that I want to prove , but How can I prove it?

Comment: OK, as a start, suppose WLOG $P_1\neq 0$. Then $P_1\equiv -\sum_{j=2}^n jP_j \bar{z}^{j-1}$. So we've got a polynomial in $z$ equal to a polynomial in $z,\bar{z}$. Any thoughts on how we can rule this out?

Comment: @Kevin Carlson Maybe I'm bad , but thinking again, I can derivate a lot of times with respect to $
{\overline z }
$ in the equality with zero, to deduce what I want to prove   for example if $$
\eqalign{
  & P\left( z \right) = P_0 \left( z \right) + P_1 \left( z \right)\overline z  + P_2 \left( z \right)\overline z ^2   \cr 
  & P_{\overline z }  = P_1 \left( z \right) + 2P_2 \left( z \right)\overline z  = 0  \cr 
  & \left( {P_{\overline z } } \right)_{\overline z }  = 0 = 2P_2 \left( z \right) \cr} 
$$
and using an inductive argument I have what I want

Comment: Hmm...the issue there is that a polynomial in $z$ doesn't have derivative 0 relative to $\bar{z}$: rather, that derivative doesn't exist. This is what I was going for before-that the left-hand side I'd gotten to was complex differentiable, while the right-hand side wasn't, unless both were constant.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Wait $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} := \frac{1}{2}( \; \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \; + \; i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\; )$$so isn't $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} (z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} (x + iy) = \frac{1}{2}(1 - 1) = 0$? For example, that's how (I think) you get $P_{\bar{z}} = \sum_j  jP_j \bar{z}^{j-1}$?

Comment: Don't be differentiating real functions with respect to a complex variable, now. If you write down the definition of the derivative of $\bar{z}$ with respect to $z$, which is more natural, you'll see it doesn't exist, simply because I can approach 0 along the real and the imaginary axes and get different results.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thanks for responding-I think there's a slight ambiguity in notation. I'm interpreting stuff as smooth functions $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, as in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivative Note that for an actually holomorphic function $f = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$, it recovers the usual notion of differentiation with respect to a complex variable, namely: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} := \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \; -  \; i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}) =^{C-R} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Comment: which is how you would calculate the regular complex derivative at $z_0$ if you took sequences coming in of the form $z_0 + r_i$, for $r_i$ real. But yeah, I agree that $\bar{z}$ isn't holomorphic for the reason you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Daniel I think your inductive argument makes sense-this is me just writing it out to make sure I understand, more or less :p. Namely, induct on the highest power of $j$ present in $P$. The claim is that $P_{\bar{z}} = 0 \Rightarrow P_j = 0 \in \mathbb{C}[z]$ for $j \geqslant 1$.

For $j = 1$, our equation $P_{\bar{z}}$ reads $P_1 = 0$ as a function, so this is the statement that if $p \in \mathbb{C}[z]$ evaluates to 0 everywhere, then $p$ is the 0 polynomial. Indeed, were it of degree $n$, for $n > 0$, it could have at most $n$ distinct roots, and $\mathbb{C}$ is infinite.

Inductively, to see that $j' < j \Rightarrow j$, suppose we have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \sum_{i \leqslant j} P_i \bar{z}^i  = \sum_{i \leqslant j} i P_i \bar{z}^{i-1} = 0
\quad \in Fun(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{C})$$Pulling the highest power to the other side, we have $$-jP_{j} \bar{z}^{j - 1} = \sum_{i < j} i P_i \bar{z}^{i - 1}$$Now apply $\frac{\partial^{j - 1}}{\partial \bar{z}^{j - 1}} \; \; \; $ to both sides, we get (up to some factorials $C$) that $$C P_j = 0 \Rightarrow P_j = 0$$by our inductive hypothesis we deduce that $P_i = 0$ for $i < j$ as well.